# Multi-Field Querying on Redis Using Redis Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, response-time

this will be a very baic question since im new to Spring-Redis

Im currently in the process of learning about Redis database and I'm working on a feature on priority, im compelled to Use Redis for this feature.
Below in the challenge/Query im having.

Right now we have a DataModel as below:

```
@RedisHash("Org_Work")
public class OrgWork {

   private @Id @Indexed UUID id;
   private @Indexed String CorpDetails;
   private @Indexed String ContractType;
   private @Indexed String ContractAssigned;
   private @Indexed String State;
   private @Indexed String Country; 

}
```

```
public interface OrgWorkRepository extends CrudRepository<HoopCalendar, String> {

List<OrgWork> findByCorpDetailsAndContractTypeAndStateAndCountry(String CorpDetails, String ContractType, String ContractAssigned, String State, String Country);

}
```

we are developing an API to query on the above Datamodel where the front-end will send us CorpDetails ,ContractType, ContractAssigned, State and Country fields and we have to query these against the Redis Database and return back the DurationOfWork object.

In this case I will be having a load of approx. 100000 calls per minute.

Please let me know on if this is the right way and some suggestions on improving response time.

***Updated the query

Comment: Is the query "CorpDetails ,ContractType, ContractAssigned, State and Country" expected to return just one result? I mean, can we treat it as a compound primary key? Or you mean to query against any combination of these fields?

Comment: we expect multiple records for the query. (the query is mentioned in OrdWorkRepository Interface)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Spring Data Redis - 8.5. Secondary Indexes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis.repositories.indexes) and:

- 8.6. Query by Example
- 8.10. Queries and Query Methods

The annotation `@Indexed` instructs Spring Data Redis (SDR) to create a secondary indexed as a [set](https://redis.io/commands/sadd) to index the field of the hash.

This means when you insert data, SDR will run seven commands to Redis:

```
HMSET "OrgWork:19315449-cda2-4f5c-b696-9cb8018fa1f9" "_class" "OrgWork" 
    "id" "19315449-cda2-4f5c-b696-9cb8018fa1f9" 
    "CorpDetails" "CorpDetailsValueHere" "ContractType" "ContractTypeValueHere" 
    ... "Country" "Costa Rica"
SADD  "OrgWork" "19315449-cda2-4f5c-b696-9cb8018fa1f9"                           
SADD  "OrgWork:CorpDetails:CorpDetailsValueHere" "19315449-cda2-4f5c-b696-9cb8018fa1f9"
SADD  "OrgWork:ContractType:ContractTypeValueHere" "19315449-cda2-4f5c-b696-9cb8018fa1f9"
...
SADD  "OrgWork:Country:Costa Rica" "19315449-cda2-4f5c-b696-9cb8018fa1f9"
```

**Using Query by Example:**

You want to create a [repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#query-by-example.execution):

```
interface OrgWorkRepository extends QueryByExampleExecutor<OrgWork> {
}
```

And then implement the query as in the example service below:

```
class OrgWorkService {

  @Autowired OrgWorkRepository orgWorkRepository;

  List<OrgWork> findOrgWorks(OrgWork probe) {
    return orgWorkRepository.findAll(Example.of(probe));
  }
}
```

And use as:

```
OrgWork orgWorkExample = new OrgWork();                          
orgWorkExample.setCorpDetails("CorpDetailsValueHere"); 
orgWorkExample.setContractType("ContractTypeValueHere");
...
List<OrgWork> results = orgWorkService.findOrgWorks(orgWorkExample);
```

Behind the scenes, SDR will take care of converting this to Redis commands to get your data, using a combination of [SINTER](https://redis.io/commands/sinter) and [HGETALL](https://redis.io/commands/hgetall):

```
SINTER   …:CorpDetails:CorpDetailsValueHere   …:ContractType:ContractTypeValueHere   ...
HGETALL "OrgWork:d70091b5-0b9a-4c0a-9551-519e61bc9ef3" 
HGETALL ...
```

This is a two-step process:

1. Fetch keys contained in the intersection of secondary indexes, using `SINTER`
2. Fetch each key returned by <1> individually, using `HGETALL`

A workload of 100,000 per minute should be manageable for Redis assuming you have a quality server, a reasonable dataset size, and the queries are somewhat specific in average.

`SINTER` has a time complexity of  O(N*M) worst-case where N is the cardinality of the smallest set and M is the number of sets. You have one set for every dimension on your query.

`HGETALL` is O(N) where N is the size of the hash, 7 in your case.

As always, it is recommended you do some benchmarking to test if you're getting the desired performance and adjust if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation @LeoMurillo .     
I have one more question.. what is the advantage of querying the way you explained over the below ?
`List<OrgWork> findByCorpDetailsAndContractTypeAndStateAndCountry(String CorpDetails, String ContractType, String ContractAssigned, String State, String Country)
`
The way I mentioned in the second part of my question?

Comment: Only the flavor of the code, on how you build the query. I figured you got one already, wanted to present the other one. I find QBE more object-oriented, the automatic derivation on CrudRepository smells a bit as long parameters; also, if you rename a field, you need to rename the function, I see a maintainability risk there, not sure if you get a compilation error or a warning or nothing in that case. A matter of taste. Behind the scenes, both should arrive to the same commands sent to Redis and exhibit the same performance

Comment: By the way, note the method name is missing AndContractAssigned, it is quite a long name :-)

Comment: Yeah Leo, even Im thinking of replacing the query with the way you just stated as it appears more OO .

Comment: I have one more small question @Leo , Is there a way we can perform a range query ... say if there is a date attribute in the pojo class, can I construct a query to retrieve the results between certain range of dates ?

like records with country US and State Washington and Date between 2019-07-19 to 2019-12-31

Comment: If it is supported is news to me, I think it isn't - it may be worth another SO question :-)

Comment: posted that question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888313/range-querying-in-redis-spring-data-jpa-redis

Thank you so much for your answer again :)