# Range Querying in Redis - Spring Data Redis

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

is there a way we can implement Range queries in Redis using Spring Data Redis?

Eg:

If my Pojo class has Date(which is not a primary key) and i require data that falls under a desired period of date, Is it possible with Spring Data Redis to construct a query for the same rather than querying each date individually?

Comment: I don't see it any operations in Spring-Redis but there's something for ordered sets https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-7-search-based-applications/7-2-sorted-indexes/7-2-1-sorting-search-results-with-zsets/ I am just trying to see if it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

For Redis **ZSets** you have `ZSetOperations`interface that have several range commands (see see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.5.1/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisZSetCommands.html), the main one being:

```
range(K key, long start, long end)
```

Plus, several `rangeByXXX` ones.

More info on Redis ZSets and range operations see https://redis.io/commands/zrange

If you want more powerful queries I recommend you take a look at RediSearch (https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/). There is Spring Integration here https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/