# Filter based on Integer Comparison in Spring data redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using spring-data-redis to communicate with database.

I have entity class like below

```
@RedisHash(value = "employee")
public class Employee
{
    @Id
    private long id;
    @Indexed
    private String name;
    @Indexed
    private int age;
    private Address address;

    ...... ...... ......

}
```

I want to filter the employees based on age group. For example, age lesser than 35 (age<35). How to achieve this in below repository?

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long>
{
    public Employee findByName(String name);
}
```

I dont prefer to load complete data from table and do search using any loop/stream.

Comment: Redis is a key-value store and it can provide you only key-based search.

Comment: Similar but unanswered as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888313/range-querying-in-redis-spring-data-redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it does.  I tried to implement what you tried to do using

```
@Index
long lastUpdatedOn;
```

when I checked the redis it gives a key `entity:lastUpdatedOn:160....` and I tried searching for it using `ZRANGE` which gives no results.