# filtering on filtered data

Tags: spring, jpa, redis, spring-data

In a spring boot project with oracle we action our queries with spring data jpa @Query and declerative method queries like findAllByXAndByZ().We have a lots of web pages that most of them have sorting and filtering.for sorting and filtering and pagination we use spring data pagination
with @Query.Then we show the data in web page form.Then,we need filtering on these filtered data!For example,user inputs s in search params (in url) then data will be filterd to words contains s. Can we use Redis cache with spring data redis for it?I mean in first step fetch data from oracle and cache it in redis,then in second step we action filtered in cache data?Or another way?

Comment: I don't see why not. Both QBE and Query are supported. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59884615/multi-field-querying-on-redis-using-redis-spring. And please post back with a more specific concern or problem if you find something not working.

Comment: Did you check https://rediSearch.io? (& https://github.com/RediSearch/spring-redisearch)

Comment: thank you i will try it,generally i think we must be use Redis

Comment: It's an extension to Redis